# Actionbarsherlock. Bar / Submenu not appearing on v4.x

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have added Actionbarsherlock to my app and added a submenu to the actionbar. On the emulator (v2.2) it works perfectly well. When I install it on my own phone (v4.1.2) the actionbar does not show.

Here is the code in the main class

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    SubMenu subMenu1 = menu.addSubMenu("Action Item");
    subMenu1.add("Sample");
    subMenu1.add("Menu");
    subMenu1.add("Items");

    MenuItem subMenu1Item = subMenu1.getItem();
    subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_dark);
    subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    return true;
}
```

I have set the following in manifest

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Any ideas on what I am missing to get this working on v4.1.2 onwards?

EDIT
I am setting a Theme up on the JAVA side (dynamic one) which is set before the SetContectView. It appears this is removing the actionbar

```
activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_BlackRed);
```

I removed the line that sets it so it does not get set and the actionbar appears. So the Question now is how to set make the actionbar to appear with this style of setting a theme

eg within theme.xml

```
<style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme">

    </style>

    <style name="Theme.BlackRed">
<!-- Number of item -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your theme extends one of the ActionBarSherlock themes. Check out their documentation for some examples: http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html

Comment: I added android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" > in my Manifest. How to extend my own theme to use them in the themes.xml file?

Comment: Instead of "<style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme">" in your themes file, use parent="Theme.Sherlock"